# TypeError: azure.DocumentDbClient is not a constructor

Tags: botframework

I'm building a bot to connect to Azure Cosmos DB using Node SDK with the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "~4.6.2",
    "botbuilder-azure": "^4.6.2",
},
```

This is the code that I copied from [this official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-cosmosdb). The tutorial is for SDK v3, unfortunately there is no official tutorial for v4 for this configuration.

```js
var azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

var documentDbOptions = {
    host: <secret>, 
    masterKey: <secret>, 
    database: 'database',   
    collection: 'collection'
};

var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient(documentDbOptions);
var cosmosStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);
```

Here is the full exception stack:

```
evandro@mypc:~/Projects/pluralsight-bot$ npm start

> pluralsight-bot@1.0.0 start /home/evandro/Projects/pluralsight-bot
> node ./index.js

/home/evandro/Projects/pluralsight-bot/index.js:28
var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient(documentDbOptions);
                  ^

TypeError: azure.DocumentDbClient is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/evandro/Projects/pluralsight-bot/index.js:28:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial you linked is dated 12/12/2017. In Bot Framework terms, that *very* out-of-date, especially since it's for v3 and not v4. At the top, it has a link to v4, although it only takes you to v4 of the docs, and not the article. [Here's more or less the same article for v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-cosmos-db).

And here's the relevant code:

```js
const { CosmosDbPartitionedStorage } = require("botbuilder-azure");

[...]

// initialized to access values in .env file.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create local Memory Storage - commented out.
// var storage = new MemoryStorage();

// Create access to CosmosDb Storage - this replaces local Memory Storage.
var storage = new CosmosDbPartitionedStorage({
    cosmosDbEndpoint: process.env.DB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT, 
    authKey: process.env.AUTH_KEY, 
    databaseId: process.env.DATABASE_ID,
    containerId: process.env.CONTAINER
})
```

Note: If you're using an existing database that is not partitioned, you'll want to use `CosmosDbStorage` and not `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage`. Also, the example in the docs incorrectly imports `CosmosDbStorage` instead of `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage`. I've submitted a PR to fix that.